# How to Prevent Unnecessary Rerenders in Function Components with Hooks in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a React project using function components and hooks, specifically `useState` and `useEffect`. I've noticed that one of my components is rerendering more often than necessary, and I'm looking for ways to optimize it to prevent these unnecessary rerenders.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [name, setName] = useState('John');

useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, [count]); // Should only update when count changes

  return (
   <div>
   <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
   <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
   <button onClick={() => setName('Jane')}>Change Name</button>
  </div>
 );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

What I've tried:

- I checked to ensure that the useEffect dependency array is set correctly.
- I've considered using React.memo, but I'm not sure if it's applicable in this context.

Expected behavior: The component should not rerender when the name state changes, only when count changes.

Comment: you can use `useRef`

Comment: Don't create React states and enqueue state updates for them if you don't want the component to rerender when they update.  If you don't render/use/reference the `name` state then it seems rather pointless for it to exist and should just be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` hook.

`useRef` is a React Hook that lets you reference a value that’s not needed for rendering.

[useRef Doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const name = useRef('John');

useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]); // Should only update when count changes

return (
   <div>
   <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
   <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
   <button onClick={() => (name.current = 'some name')}>Change Name</button>
  </div>
 );
};

export default MyComponent;
```